# jQUery --> hash changing after clicking given menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

How to make url change hash after clicking given menu item ? (description below shows how I want it to work):

1. I click given menu item
2. window scrolls to corresponding to that menu item section
3. url adress is changing hash to corresponding to clicked menu item hash

This is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d1abevro/5/

I need to place the following code snipets to the code below to change hash:

```
var target = this.hash;
$target = $(target);

location.hash = target;
```

This is the code where I need to place those snipets somewhere (I tried but to no avail):

```
$(document).on("click.menuLinkEvent", "a.c-main-menu__link:not(a.c-main-menu__link[href='#main-header'])", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 56
  }, 800);
  $('.c-main-menu ul').slideToggle();
});
```

When I try to place those snipets I especially noticed strange behavior for mobile menu (max-width 480 breakpoint).

Comment: Have you tried `window.location.hash = this.hash`

Comment: ok I added window.location.hash = this.hash to my page and it works except after each time I click menu item the page reloads. This is my page: https://robothabanera.github.io/box/

Comment: @abagshaw ok try it now https://robothabanera.github.io/box/